# How to scan a document from UIImage in iOS?

Tags: ios6, uiimage, image-scanner

Can anyone tell me how to scan the document part from UIImage after clicking the image from camera.I want to cut the document part from the rest of the image. I search a lot about this but didn't find anything helpful.
Can anyone share any helpful links and tutorials in this regards.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This will not be an easy task, I guess you will have to code all this your self. You will write code to analyze the image and see if there is a document in there. The you will need to OCR the document if you want to convert it into text. I'm guessing no will answer this question with a full solution.

Comment: @rckoenes can you please share me any helpful data if you know,regarding this topic.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could have a look at the OCR projects like the tesseract project

https://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo

http://robertcarlsen.net/dev/pocket-ocr

Hope this helps.